# How to rotate only one screen in a screen hierarchy

Tags: ios5, rotation

My app has a  hierarchy set up like this:

```
UITabBarCOntroller
    |
    UINavigationController1
    |  |
    |  UITableViewController1
    |     |
    |     UIViewController1
    |        |
    |        UIViewController2
    |
    UINavigationController2
       |
       UITableViewController2
          |
          UIViewController3
```

I want to rotate only UIViewController2 and the other ViewControllers remain UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just present the UIViewController2 as a **modal** view controller. This way you can rotate `UIViewController` independently from the parent `UIViewController`s. You can find source code examples [here](http://timneill.net/2010/09/modal-view-controller-example-part-1/).